# GLIB_GSETTINGS not found while compiling gnome extension

Tags: gnome

Having failed to install a gnome extension from the website I looked for another way. The guide I found on google was like:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-common
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-shell-extensions
cd gnome-shell-extensions
./autogen.sh --prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-extensions="drop-down-terminal"
```

The last command failed though with the following error:

```
./configure: line 4276: GLIB_GSETTINGS: command not found
configure: error: invalid extension drop-down-terminal
```

Unfortunately I didn't find anything helpful on google.
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure script failures are hard to read.
Most likely you are missing a development library.

If this package already exists in ubuntu but you want to compile a newer version, you can do something like:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-shell-extensions
```

This will install all missing build dependencies.

Comment: 'Unable to find a source package for gnome-shell-extensions'. You got it right though, the package needed was libglib2.0-dev